# Adding number of months (as integer) to date format in QGIS

Tags: qgis, date, format, default, forms

I am creating a form for QFIELD in a QGIS project.

I have three fields:

- Date of today (`[$now]`), as a date format,
- Number of months allocated for a certain task, as an integer
- The due date for this task, as a date format too.

What expression should I write into the default box to compute the due date? I have tried many things without any success.

Comment: It is a) unclear, what fields you actually have and which you need to create, and b) unclear, what exactly you tried so far. Can you provide example data?

Comment: I have the fields: todaysdate (date), monthsnumber (int) and Finaldate (date). What i would like to achieve is, when i fill in QFIELD the todaysdate and monthsnumber, the box from Finaldate automatically update with the sume of todaysdate + months number.
Ej, todays date = 20-11-202, monthsnumber = 4, finaldate (automatically)= 20-03-2020

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add an interval of time to the date. This interval can can be hard coded or read from another field

```
now() + to_interval('3 month')

oldDate + to_interval( myIntervalIntegerValue || ' month')
```

Comment: This solution seems to work perfectly, just comment that whenever you increment the namber of months, the days are dicreasing. Example, when I try to add 24 months to the actual date 20-11-2020 it genereates 10 days less 10-11-2022 instead of 20-11-2022. However, i find it a good solution.

Comment: @Serggg182 Yes, interval assumes every month is 30 days. If we print `to_interval('12 month')` we get `360` days only. Beware of `to_interval('1 year')` which is 365.25 days (effectively changing the hour). The most accurate solution would be to convert to a number of days (but then to simplify the number of days in February and the 30 - 31 days, you will come with an average of 30 days per month... back to original behavior :)

Answer (score 4):

You can also use pyqgis:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import * #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35066588/is-there-a-simple-way-to-increment-a-datetime-object-one-month-in-python/35067328

lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Refactored')[0] #Change to match your data
datefield = 'datefield' #Change
monthfield = 'months' #Change
duefield = 'Due_date' #Change

with edit(lyr):
    for f in lyr.getFeatures():
        newdate = QDate(f[datefield].toPyDate()+relativedelta(months=+f[monthfield]))
        f[duefield] = newdate
        lyr.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]